# Cloud Formation does not create API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently building a serverless REST API using AWS.

I've created a project with the Serverless Framework and created a pipeline for building and releasing the API.

After the first execution, the pipline created all the resources and the API Gateway with all the endpoint I expected.

After that, every modification to the project seemed to take no effect: no modifications were deployed.

Finally I tried to delete the API from the API gateway console. I executed the pipeline again but the API was not created again. Needless to say, the execution of the pipeline reported success.

What could be the problem? This is my serverless.yml file:

```
service: muthh-api

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-reqvalidator-plugin
  - serverless-aws-documentation

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: prod
  region: us-east-1
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 5
  environment:
    CHECKLIST_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-CHECKLIST
    TASK_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-TASK
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action: 
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TASK_TABLE}"
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TASK_TABLE}/index/*"
    - Effect: Allow
      Action: 
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.CHECKLIST_TABLE}"
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.CHECKLIST_TABLE}/index/*"

custom:
  allowedHeaders:
    - Accept
    - Content-Type
    - Content-Length
    - Authorization
    - X-Amz-Date
    - X-Api-Key
    - X-Amz-Security-Token
    - X-Amz-User-Agent
    - app_user_id
    - app_user_name
  documentation:
    api:
      info:
        version: '1.0.0'
        title: Muth API
        description: Muth API
      tags:
        -
          name: Task
          description: Task Management
    models:
      # Checklist Models
      - name: AddChecklistRequest
        contentType: "application/json"
        schema:
          required: 
            - user_id
            - title
          properties:
            user_id:
              type: string
            title:
              type: string
      - name: UpdateChecklistRequest
        contentType: "application/json"
        schema:
          required: 
            - user_id
            - checklist_id
            - title
          properties:
            user_id:
              type: string
            checklist_id:
              type: string
            title:
              type: string
      # Task Models
      - name: AddTaskRequest
        contentType: "application/json"
        schema:
          required: 
            - user_id
            - checklist_id
            - title
            - order
          properties:
            user_id:
              type: string
            checklist_id:
              type: string
            title:
              type: string
            order:
              type: number
      - name: UpdateTaskRequest
        contentType: "application/json"
        schema:
          required: 
            - task_id
            - user_id
            - checklist_id
            - title
            - order
          properties:
            user_id:
              type: string
            task_id:
              type: string
            checklist_id:
              type: string
            title:
              type: string
            order:
              type: number

functions:
  # Checklist API
  get-checklist:
    handler: api/checklist/get-checklist.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: checklist/{id}
          method: get
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}

  get-checklists:
    handler: api/checklist/get-checklist.getList
    events:
      - http:
          path: checklists/{id}
          method: get
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}

  update-checklist:
    handler: api/checklist/update-checklist.update
    events:
      - http:
          documentation:
            summary: "Update checklist"
            description: "Updates a checklist"
            tags:
              - Checklist
            requestModels:
              "application/json": UpdateChecklistRequest
          path: checklist
          method: patch
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}


  add-checklist:
    handler: api/checklist/add-checklist.add
    events:
      - http:
          documentation:
            summary: "Add checklist"
            description: "Adds a new user checklist"
            tags:
              - Checklist
            requestModels:
              "application/json": AddChecklistRequest
          path: checklist
          method: post
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
          reqValidatorName: onlyBody

  delete-checklist:
    handler: api/checklist/delete-checklist.delete
    events:
      - http:
          path: checklist/{id}
          method: delete
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}

  # Task API
  get-task:
    handler: api/task/get-task.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: task/{id}
          method: get
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}

  get-tasks:
    handler: api/task/get-task.getList
    events:
      - http:
          path: tasks/{id}
          method: get
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}

  update-task:
    handler: api/task/update-task.update
    events:
      - http:
          documentation:
            summary: "Update task"
            description: "Updates a task in checklist"
            tags:
              - Task
            requestModels:
              "application/json": UpdateTaskRequest
          path: task
          method: patch
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}

  complete-task:
    handler: api/task/update-task.complete
    events:
      - http:
          path: complete_task/{id}
          method: patch
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}

  add-task:
    handler: api/task/add-task.add
    events:
      - http:
          documentation:
            summary: "Add task"
            description: "Adds a new task to checklist"
            tags:
              - Task
            requestModels:
              "application/json": AddTaskRequest
          path: task
          method: post
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
          reqValidatorName: onlyBody

  delete-task:
    handler: api/task/delete-task.delete
    events:
      - http:
          path: task/{id}
          method: delete
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}

resources:
  Resources:
    onlyBody:  
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator"
      Properties:
        Name: 'only-body'
        RestApiId: 
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        ValidateRequestBody: true
        ValidateRequestParameters: false

    # Checklist Table
    ChecklistTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.CHECKLIST_TABLE}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: checklist_id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: user_id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: checklist_id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: user_id-index
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: user_id
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1

    # Task Table
    TaskTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.TASK_TABLE}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: task_id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: checklist_id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: task_id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: checklist_id-index
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: checklist_id
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Comment: You shouldn't remove resources created by a CloudFormation template by other means. I would suggest destroying the entire stack and deploying it back again.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "deployed". Once an API Gateway deployment resource is created, further updates to Resource or Method types for that deployment will not be deployed (as in, in API Gateway). But the resources themselves should be created or updated. So it depends what you mean by "deployed".

Comment: I've already tried to remove the whole stack, but that didn't work. My deploy works with CodePipeline: I have a code commit repository where every push on the master branch triggers a CodeBuild job.

Comment: Do you have AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment resource defined? Could you share the simplified part of the configuration responsible for what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I see ApiGatewayRestApi referenced but not defined in the .yml you posted

Can you show us the CloudFormation template that is attempting to create the Api Gateway API?